# How to scp via an intermediate machine?

Tags: linux, ssh, scp

In order to ssh into my work computer from home, let's call it `C` I have to do the following:

```
ssh -t user@B ssh C
```

B is a server that I can connect to from home but C can only be connected to from B.  This works fine.

If I want to copy a file that is on C to my home computer using `scp`, what command do I need from my home computer?

Comment: You're probably looking for `ssh proxycommand`

Comment: @thrig That sounds interesting.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/456438/how-do-i-scp-a-file-through-an-intermediate-server

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I’d suggest the following in your `.ssh/config`:

```
Host C
    User user
    ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p user@B
```

I’t much safer if host B is untrusted, and works for scp and sftp.

Comment: What permissions does .ssh/config need?

Comment: How do I specify the username for C? It's the same as the username for B but different from my local username.

Comment: This answer works. I did `scp user@C`. Thank you.

Comment: @Lembik You can also add `User user` within the `Host C` section of your `.ssh/config` file and then run `scp C`. And please consider accepting an answer (mine or anyone else’s).

Comment: Can you elaborate on what exactly this is doing and why it's safer? (also, safer than what?)

Answer (score 10):

As described in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/333052/20246), you can use the `ProxyCommand` directive to have an `ssh` host bounce you to a third host transparently:

Let's say you have the following three hosts:

- `workstation.example.com` - This is the machine you're physically working on
- `proxy.example.com` - This is the machine you're routing your SSH traffic through
- `endpoint.example.com` - This is where you want the traffic to ultimately end up

In `~/.ssh/config` on `workstation`, add the following:

```
Host endpoint
    User endpointUser # set this to the username on the endpoint host
    HostName endpoint.example.com
    ProxyCommand ssh proxyusername@proxy.example.com nc %h %p 2> /dev/null
```

On the `proxy` host, make sure `nc` (netcat) is installed.

Then, on `workstation`, you can `ssh endpoint` or `sftp endpoint` and you will be transparently proxied to the machine by way of your proxy host.  `scp` will also work.

Comment: What permissions does .ssh/config need?

Comment: 0644; the configuration needs to be readable by the `ssh` client.

Comment: @Lembik `chmod 0711 ~/.ssh; chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/config`

Comment: I prefer `ssh -W` over `ssh nc` because `nc` might be missing in the proxy host.

Comment: Generally inclined to agree, but I have had issues where using netcat worked and `ssh -W` did not, so I tend to fall back on netcat.

Comment: @DopeGhoti Good to know, if I ever have problems with `ssh -W`.

Comment: Sadly it's not working for me. It asks for my password for proxy.example.com but never asks for the password for endpoint.example.com.  Ends with "ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host". See https://bpaste.net/show/5ef06924ef3e

Comment: If you have different usernames at the proxy and the endpoint, be sure to specify them as shown.  You could also use keypair authentication on both hosts to not need to present your password (after giving your private key's passphrase, of course).

Comment: The username for B and C are the same as each other but different from my local user name.

Comment: Okay, so in the configuration, specify that username both on the `User` line and in the `ProxyCommand` line (i. e. replace `proxyuser` with the actual username).

Answer (score 7):

It's possible and relatively easy, even when you need to use certificates for authentication (typical in AWS environments).

The command below will copy files from a remotePath on server2 directly into your machine at localPath. Internally the scp request is proxied via server1.

```
scp -i user2-cert.pem -o ProxyCommand="ssh -i user1-cert.pem -W %h:%p user1@server1" user2@server2:/<remotePath> <localpath>
```

If you use password authentication instead, try with

```
scp -o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p user1@server1" user2@server2:/<remotePath> <localpath>
```

If you use the same user credentials in both servers:

```
scp -o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p commonuser@server1" commonuser@server2:/<remotePath> <localpath>
```

Comment: This answer should be at the top. Instances get terminated and replaced all the time. I'd rather not hardcode them in my ssh config.

Comment: Totally agreed. Very useful

Comment: What is the meaning of `%h:%p`?

Comment: I agree, this is a much better answer in situations where there are a lot of ephemeral instances and updaing sshconfig for each IP is not possible. It's easier to put the above function in an alias and re-use.